# Dynamically construct SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

It's my third day of learning PHP and I ran into a problem. My UPDATE and INSERT PDO querys are running fine, but I have complications getting the SELECT query working dynamically.

This is my search form:

```
<h1>Search</h1> 
<form action="otsingu_tulemused.php" method="post"> 
    Aadress:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="aadress" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Hind:<br />
    <input type="text" name="hind" value="" /><br /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Otsi" /> 
</form>
```

And this is my search results page:

```
<?php 

    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("common.php"); 


    // This if statement checks to determine whether the edit form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the account updating code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 

//        Vaatame, kas aadressi väli on täidetud
        if(!empty($_POST['aadress'])) 
        { 
            $aadress = $_POST['aadress']; 
        }
        else {
            $aadress = null;
        } 
//        Vaatame, kas hinna väli on täidetud
        if(!empty($_POST['hind'])) 
        { 
            $hind = $_POST['hind']; 
        }
        else {
            $hind = null;
        } 
//      Kui aadressi väli on täidetud, siis anname parameetrile väärtuse        
        if($aadress !== null) 
        { 
            $query_params[':addr'] = $aadress; 
        }
//      Kui hinna väli on täidetud, siis anname parameetrile väärtuse           
        if($hind !== null) 
        { 
            $query_params[':price'] = $hind; 
        } 

        // Note how this is only first half of the necessary update query.  We will dynamically 
        // construct the rest of it depending on whether or not the user is changing 
        // their password. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM kuulutused 
            WHERE 
        "; 

        // If the user is changing their password, then we extend the SQL query 
        // to include the password and salt columns and parameter tokens too. 
        if($address !== null) 
        { 
            $query .= " 
                addr LIKE :addr 
            "; 
        } 
        if($price !== null) 
        { 
            $query .= " 
            AND
                price = :price 
            "; 
        } 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

?>
 <table class="table">
<?php foreach( $result as $row ){
   echo "<tr><td>";
     echo $row['addr'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['price'];
     echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
?>
</table>
```

This query gives me an error:

> Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4.

Comment: try to echo the output of "$query" variable

Comment: if $address is not set and $price is set, you end up with "WHERE AND price = :price"

Comment: The query comes out like this when aadress field is entered. SELECT * FROM kuulutused WHERE 1=1 AND addr LIKE :addr , but it seems that it wont take in the :addr prepared statement value.

Comment: What value are you binding?

Comment: $aadress = $_POST['aadress']; this should be :addr parameter. $query_params[':addr'] = $aadress; this is where :addr should get the value.

Comment: I mean the final value. What is in $_POST['aadress']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no condition is set, your query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM kuulutused WHERE
```

As you see, WHERE is empty, syntax error.

if $address is not set and $price is set, you end up with

```
SELECT * FROM kuulutused WHERE AND price = :price
```

Again, syntax error.

With mysql, you can start with:

```
SELECT * FROM kuulutused WHERE 1
```

Then always add `AND column = :value`, or `AND column LIKE :value`

Comment: Perhaps because you want to do fulltext? Then you have to suround the search by %: $query_params[':addr'] = '%'.$aadress.'%';

Comment: Thanks! Well I couldn't get it to work with the code I had, but i used WHERE 1=1 and recoded the whole thing. Now it is working completely fine!

Answer (score -2):

Syntax error
Missing %  in like using PDO

Also you have to check that `where` clause coming with given conditions.

Comment: This is parameter binding, so no quotes. LIKE comparison does not mean it has to have %.